# Sum rows of numpy array where start index of each sum comes from another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `NxM` numpy array called `data`.
I also have a length `N` array called `start_indices`.
I want a new length `M` array where the ith element is `sum(data[i][start_indices[i]:])`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.linspace(0, 11, 12).reshape((3, 4))
data
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [8, 9, 10, 11]])
start_indices = np.array([0, 1, 2])
sums = []
for start_index, row in zip(start_indices, data):
    sums.append(np.sum(row[start_index:]))
sums = np.array(sums)
```

Is there a more numpythonic way?

Comment: Your loop could be recast as a list comprehension: `np.array([np.sum(row[s:]) for s, row in zip(start,data)])`.  But no real difference in speed.

Comment: ^ indeed.. but the zip operation is not really needed though, might as well index the arrays without making new ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a mask array

```
>>> mask = start_indices[:,None] <= np.arange(data.shape[1])
>>> (data * mask).sum(axis=1)
array([  6.,  18.,  21.])
```

For, the last step you may also use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
>>> np.einsum('ij,ij->i', data, mask)
array([  6.,  18.,  21.])
```

though using a mask array here may be inefficient and iterate too many indices.

Alternatively, [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
>>> it = (r[i:].sum() for r, i in zip(data, start_indices))
>>> np.fromiter(it, data.dtype)
array([  6.,  18.,  21.])
```

Comment: In small time tests, all variations of the `zip` iteration take about the same time; the iteration methods are just syntatic sugar.  But the masked `einsum` is better than 2x faster.  I wonder how it scales.

Comment: This masking is cute, but the matrix multiplication will get very slow as the size of ```data``` increases. Even the ```einsum``` looses to list comprehension as ```size(data)``` is increased. I tested and it seems the ```np.fromiter```and simple comprehension without zipping (my answer!) are the fastest of the methods proposed.

Comment: Accepted for `fromiter` because it's easy to understand and as fast as the `cumsum` method from hpaulj (assuming I used `timeit` right).

Answer (score 2):

Besides the zip iteration (several forms) and the masked sum, `cumsum` might be worth testing

```
data[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1)[range(data.shape[0]), data.shape[1]-1-start_indices]
```

The `cumsum` on the correct axis is easy; most of the expression is used to pull out the desired sums.

In this small case it is faster than the zip iteration, but slower than the masked sums.  But rankings may change with size.

I don't consider any of these alternatives more 'pythonic'.  They also use approved Python methods.  Ones that avoid the zip iteration might get `numpy` brownie points, but only if they improve speed where it matters.

`np.reduceat` promises even better speed (first cut, not generalized):

```
np.add.reduceat(data.ravel(),[0,4,5,8,10])[::2]
```

This is a test expression, and doesn't take into account the time it takes to generate the `indices` list

```
indices = np.array([0,4,4,8,8]); indices[::2] += start_indices
```

Comment: The `reduceat` idea is interesting. The `cumsum` idea is almost perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
sums = np.array( [data[i, start_indices[i]:].sum() for i in range(data.shape[0])] )
```